# How to determine what CVE is back ported to what version of package?

Tags: apache-2.4, oracle, sysadmin, spacewalk, cve

I'm trying to determine what version of apache is backported for CVE-2021-40438.  I'm very confused as to how to find out.  Our spacewalk server has multiple apache versions of 2.4.37 from -10 to -56 and the specific VM is up to date with 2.4.37-56.0.1.module+el8.8.0+21057+13668aee.6

Answer (score 0):

By any means I am an expert on Linux, but here's my 2 cents...

You will have to use your Operating System security advisories to tie back CVEs to specific releases. Apparently, Apache only ties CVEs to Apache versions.

For example, if you have Oracle Linux at 2.4.37-56.0.1.module+el8.8.0+21057+13668aee.6

you'll know CVE-2021-40438 is fixed looking at the following security advisory because it states that CVE-2021-40438 is resolved on httpd-2.4.37-39.0.1

https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2021-3816.html